# get URL using Regex

Tags: regex, windows-phone-7, c#-4.0

I am trying to extract a URL from

```
<description>
<![CDATA[
<img src="http://www.jawharafm.net/Galerie/admin/?public&action=photo_large&key=RuQhuDKGNA52" alt="" />
]]>
</description>
```

I used this code:

```
photo = Regex.Matches(res.Element("description").Value, "http://.*.()")[0].Value;
```

but this returns all data beginning from `http` until `alt=""` ps I have a whole file of description balises so I can't make it end by just `52` or the whole key because it's dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`https?://[^"]*` should do the trick. (the string literal for C# is `@"https?://[^""]*"`)

Comment: This is ok for http urls but will not match https urls.

Answer (score 0):

This pattern will make the job :

```
(?<=src=")([^"]*)(?=")
```

With doubled double quote for string litteral as said @davidrac :

```
@"(?<=src="")([^""]*)(?="")"
```